# How to merge Arrows in PlantUML

Tags: plantuml

i am new to PlantUML (and stackoverflow) and could need some help with arrows i PlantUML. You can see the Diagram in the Picture.

[image]

How can i order them Better, so that there is one Line between "Anwendungen MES" and "Database" from which one Arrow points to "Database".

Comment: Hello. It would be helpful to inline your plantuml code by editing your question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Without the original PlantUML diagram it is impossible to know for sure, but...

To draw an arrow between "Anwendungen MES" and "Datenbanken", this should work:

```
"Anwendungen MES" --> "Datenbanken"
```

### Image

[image]

### Diagram

```
@startuml
folder Benutzer {
    component "Benutzer 1" as b1
    component "Benutzer 2" as b2
    component "Benutzer 3" as b3
}

folder "Anwendungen MES" {
    component "Wartung und Instandhaltung" as WI
    component "Qualitätsmanagement" as QM
    component "Produktionsüberwachung" as PU
    component "Auftragsmanagement" as AM
}

folder Datenbanken {
    component "Mittelfristige Daten" as MD
    component "Langzeitdaten" as LD
    component "Echtzeitdaten" as ED
}

folder Fertigung {
    component "Terminals"
    component "Anlagen"
    component "Maschinen"
}

b1 -d-> WI
b1 -d-> QM
b2 -d-> PU
b3 -d-> PU
b3 -d-> AM

"Anwendungen MES" ---> "Datenbanken"

Terminals -u-> ED
Anlagen -u-> ED
Maschinen -u-> ED
@enduml
```